# iOS Displaying a pdf in WebView using Google Drive Doc View

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, uiwebview, google-document-viewer

I explored many sites and obtained the following instruction that displays a pdf file in a very beautiful way.

```
[_pdfViewer loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://gamersgold.com/wop-ios/uploads/eula_terms.pdf"]]];
```

However this URL is mainly used in Android apps:

```
http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=
```

When using it the `Google Docs` caption is displayed at the bottom of the page. Would using this method cause my app to be rejected by the App Store?

Is there any alternative approach to achieve this in iOS that is provided or approved by Apple?

Comment: I don't think you should tag this with android, question is entirely related to ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this `http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=` will not get your app rejected.

Still if you have doubt, it is not necessary to use this URl. You can directly code like below and it will display the PDF in UIWebView object. You can say this is an alternative, infact, the default way to display a PDF file in UIWebView

```
[_pdfViewer loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://gamersgold.com/wop-ios/uploads/eula_terms.pdf"]]];}
```